# error in mq_open: invalid argument

Tags: linux, message-queue

Can anyone help me point out where is the errors in my code?
Thank you in advance.

Here is my code.I delete header files in code below.When I ran these code ,I always receive

> :mq_open:invalid argument

```
#define FILE_MODE S_IRUSR|S_IWUSR|S_IRGRP|S_IROTH
struct mq_attr attr;
int main (int argc,char **argv)
{
    int c;
    int flags;
    mqd_t mqd;

    flags = O_RDWR|O_CREAT;

    while ( (c = getopt (argc,argv,"em:z:")) != -1) {
        switch (c) {
            case 'e':
                flags |= O_EXCL;
                continue;

            case 'm':
                attr.mq_maxmsg = atol (optarg);
                break;

            case 'z':
                attr.mq_msgsize = atol (optarg);
                break;
        }
    }

    if (optind != argc - 1) {
        printf ("usage:mqcreate [-e] [-m maxseg -z msgsize] <name>\n");
        exit (1);
    }

    if ((attr.mq_maxmsg != 0 && attr.mq_msgsize == 0) ||
            (attr.mq_maxmsg == 0 && attr.mq_msgsize != 0))
    {
        printf ("must specify both -m maxmsg and -z msgsize\n");
        exit (1);
    }

    if (attr.mq_msgsize == 0 && attr.mq_maxmsg == 0)
    {
        attr.mq_msgsize = 10;
        attr.mq_maxmsg = 10;
    }


    mqd = mq_open (argv[optind],flags,FILE_MODE,&attr);
    if (mqd == -1) {
       perror ("mq_open");
       exit (1);
   }

   mq_close (mqd);

   return 0;
}
```

I search stackoverflow for this question,but none helps me.
Thank you.

Comment: Please tell us what command line args were passed to the program.

Comment: I use gcc to compile these code: gcc -g mqcreate.c -o mqcreate -lrt  and I run mqcreate with -e -m 1024 -z 8192 ./foobar. These code are from unp value 2.

Comment: Try `/foobar` instead of `./foobar`. The [mq_overview man page says](https://linux.die.net/man/7/mq_overview): "Each message queue is identified by a name of the form */somename*. that is, a null-terminated string of up to NAME_MAX (i.e., 255) characters consisting of an initial slash, followed by one or more characters, none of which are slashes. "

Comment: Yes,thank you.please forgive for not watching the mq_overview man page carefully.I  watched it about one hour age,and I focused on the limit amoung mq_maxmsg and mq_msgsize.Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

`./foobar` is not a valid value for the mq name. The [mq_overview man page](https://linux.die.net/man/7/mq_overview):

> Each message queue is identified by a name of the form /somename; that
>   is, a null-terminated string of up to NAME_MAX (i.e., 255) characters
>   consisting of an initial slash, followed by one or more characters,
>   none of which are slashes.

So run the program with name arg `/foobar` instead of `./foobar`.

Comment: But where can I find mesage queue files created by mq_open?

Comment: Please read the man page: "Mounting the message queue filesystem: On Linux, message queues are created in a virtual  filesystem....."